# python dataframe drop rows in all columns outside the predefined limits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am dropping rows in all columns of the df if they fall outside the specified limit.

my code:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'],data=[[-10,20],[2,8],[4,1],[3,-1]])
print(xdf)
xdf_params_limits = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'],index=['min','max'],data=[[0,1],[5,30]])
print(xdf_params_limits)
xdf_flt = xdf.apply(lambda x: (x[col]>xdf_params_limits[col].loc['min'])&(x[col]<xdf_params_limits[col].loc['max']) for col in xdf.columns, axis=1)
xdf = xdf[xdf_flt]

    A   B
0 -10  20
1   2   8
2   4   1
3   3  -1
     A   B
min  0   1
max  5  30
```

Expected output

xdf =

```
    A   B
1   2   8
```

Present output:

```
     81 def ast_parse(self, source, filename='<unknown>', symbol='exec'):
     82     """Parse code to an AST with the current compiler flags active.
     83 
     84     Arguments are exactly the same as ast.parse (in the standard library),
     85     and are passed to the built-in compile function."""
---> 86     return compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags | PyCF_ONLY_AST, 1)

SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized (2981748052.py, line 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using simple [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with two masks and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
out = xdf.loc[(xdf.gt(xdf_params_limits.loc['min'])
              &xdf.lt(xdf_params_limits.loc['max'])
              ).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
1  2  8
```

Intermediates:

```
xdf.gt(xdf_params_limits.loc['min'])

       A      B
0  False   True
1   True   True
2   True  False
3   True  False

xdf.lt(xdf_params_limits.loc['max'])

      A     B
0  True  True
1  True  True
2  True  True
3  True  True
```

Comment: Yep, that's the best way probably (that is what I attempted to do, using numpy, because I didn't knew about `.lt` and `.gt`)

Comment: Do the columns in both data frames have to be in the same order prior to performing `gt` or `lt`? or this parameter inherently looks for the matching column names?

Comment: Another simple solution easy to understand. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Mainland pandas performs index/columns alignment before computations, order doesn't matter ;)

Comment: I am slowly understanding the power of pandas. I mean, being a non-programmer and non-computers background, I commend its ability to do so many things inherently. For example, here, in this case, its ability to perform index/column alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Getting boolean mask with `np.column_stack(...).any(1)`:

```
xdf[np.column_stack([(xdf[c] > xdf_params_limits[c]['min']) \
    & (xdf[c] < xdf_params_limits[c]['max']) for c in xdf.columns]).all(1)]
```

---

```
   A  B
1  2  8
```

Answer (score 1):

The first rules of pandas, is "never use for". The second is "never use apply".

So, if you want a fast computation, you need to think globally.

Now, there are exceptions to these rules. For example, if you have many rows, but only a few columns, then iterating over columns is ok. And then the answers you got, that are doing that, are ok.

If you may have many columns also, then you need to also vectorize what happens along columns.

One way is to use numpy

```py
xdf[((xdf.values > xdf_params_limits.values[:1,:]) & (xdf.values < xdf_params_limits.values[1:,:])).all(axis=1)]
```

What it does is comparing all values with the "minimum line" and with the "maximum" line (counting on numpy's broadcasting to compare n rows to single rows), to create a boolean index to be used as selector.

The `xdf_params_limits.values[:1,:]` and `xdf_params_limits.values[1:,:]` is just lazy way to select `min` and `max` row, and then add a new axis. I could have gone with `xdf_params_limits.loc['min'].values[np.newaxis,:]` and `xdf_params_limits.loc['max'].values[np.newaxis,:]` also.

Comment: Really nice points for me to learn. So, don't use `for`, `apply`. I thought `apply` is a vectored approach as it goes through entire column in one go. So, I am wrong. I even tried above using for loop going to each column.

Comment: Also, what surprises me most is, the entire answer I wanted seems to be a simple code and this seems to be inherently available. Meaning, I don't have to use for and apply methods as you pointed. Also, what I am surprised at is `xdf.values > xdf_params_limits.values[:1,:]` is comparing entire df values with the corresponding min values of all columns. I have one question: `xdf_params_limits.loc['min'].values[np.newaxis,:]` what is the `np.newaxis` here? This is first time I heard about since I started  learning Python 5 years ago.

Comment: @Mainland `np.newaxis` is just an alias for `None`, which makes it more readable for human. Indexing an array with `None` means `add a new, size 1, axis here. For example, if you have a 2D-array `A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` (shape (2,3)), then `A[:,:,None]` adds a third axis for each index combination, to get shape (2,3,1) array: `[[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]]`. `A[:,None,:]` insert an axis in 2nd axis, to get shape (2,1,3) array: `[[[1,2,3]], [[4,5,6]]]`. And lastly `A[None,:,:]` adds it as first axis to get array of shape (1,2,3) `[[[1,2],[3,4]]]`

Comment: @Mainland Note that @mozway answer is roughly the same, but probably preferable. You can see the same kind of steps: comparing all values at once with 2 rows of limits, then checking that all comparison succeeds with `all(axis=1)` and then using that boolean series to index the dataframe. I haven't timed mine and theirs. But it is probably very similar in timing too. And using pandas function is better than my using of `.value` then numpy, because it doesn't make asumption on the order of values being the same.

Comment: @Mainland. Sure, this assumption is true. But still, the less assumption you need, the better off you are. Plus, `numpy` is available only for numerical values (or at least, numpy is efficient only for numerical values. Hence the `num` in its name). If you wanted to extend this kind of code for some string comparison or datetime, or something else, it is easier to adapt if your code is using pandas primitive. My using of numpy is just because of my being more comfortable with numpy (tbh, first time I hear about `.gt` and `.lt` methods of pandas)

Comment: Really nice explanation, particularly about `newaxis`. I have not heard this before. Thanks a ton for the new knowledge and learning.